# How to use Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect from ajax UpdatePanel?

Tags: ajax, updatepanel, response, server.transfer

How to use Server.Transfer or Response.Redirect from ajax UpdatePanel?

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having in more detail.

Answer (score 1):

Without being harsh, it really doesn't make sense to be able to. I think some reading about AJAX would make it clear.

But you could write following to the browser.

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "URL"</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i just found out myself
use javascript inside ur Updatepanel like the code below.

### c# code:

> String TransferPage =
>   "window.open('Gallery-Page.aspx','_self');";
>   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page,
>   Page.GetType(), "temp", TransferPage,
>   false);

Even u can give hyperlink instead of "Gallery-Page.aspx"
Thanks,
Asem Ibohal

Comment: @Eibx's solution using window.location is better, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

UpdatePanel supports Response.Redirect. It works OK for me. What error do you get?